# Double sequence convergence

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let be $$S(m,k)$$
  number of partitions of a $k$ element set into $m$ nonempty parts investigating with generating functions I get this very interesting equation$$\sum_{k=0}^ {\infty}\sum_{m=0}^ {\infty}S(m,k)\frac{1}{k!}=e^{e-1} $$
Can someone tell me if I am right.

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion?  Off hand, I know only one way to do it: the one that's currently in the Wikipedia article on Dobinski's formula.  I actually suspect I've read another derivation of it at some point, but I don't remember any more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner sum actually has a finite number of non-zero members:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^ {\infty}S(m,k)=
\sum_{m=0}^ {k}S(m,k)=B_k
$$
where $B_k$ are the [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions).
The exponential generating function for them is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k x^k}{k!}=e^{e^x-1}.$$ Putting $x=1$ gives the required equality.

Comment: +1. You could have mentioned something about Stirling subset numbers though... :)

Comment: @J. M. They're mentioned in the reference, so I decided not to expand :)

Answer (score 0):

Two comments: (1) There is a wikipedia article about this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula

and (2) the conventional notation for Stirling numbers is that $S(m,k)$ is the number of partitions of a set of size $m$ into $k$ subsets, not the number of partitions of a set of size $k$ into $m$ subsets.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number